# How can I use multi-meter to measure the resistance of a solution?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrochemistry

I want to measure the resistance of saltwater solution. I am using a multimeter but I do not know how to use it to measure the resistance. Please help

Comment: Does your multimeter measure resistance directly?

Comment: yes, I am measuring the resistance directly

Answer (score 2):

Increase the surface area of the meter's probes by using something like aluminum foil, or a metal screen. The surface area of the probe needs to be approximately the same as the cross section of the volume of water across which you want to measure the resistance.

Comment: could you please be more specific? how do you measure the cross-section of volume of water?

Comment: If the solution fills a rectangular container of dimensions L x W, to a depth of D, and you are measuring the resistance across the L dimension, then the cross section area is W x D.